Plotly Express - how to set date slider on x,y scatter plot
I'm trying to make a scatter plot that allows me to do a couple things:

Toggle a selected date range that automatically displays the coordinates for each day within the range - I figure some sort of slider would be used, but haven't been able to get one to work.
Identify the start and end date - I've thought about using a heatmap to show the coordinates path over the date range

Here is some of the data:
Date            x   y
2024-10-09  0.08    4.83
2024-10-16  0.01    4.83
2024-10-23  0.28    4.83
2024-10-30  0.24    4.83
2024-11-06  0.32    4.83
2024-11-13  0.64    4.62
2024-11-20  0.62    4.58
2024-11-27  0.49    4.58
2024-12-04  0.39    4.58
2024-12-11  0.52    4.58
The basic scatter plot works:
fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", width=600, height=600,
                range_x=[df['x'].min(), df['x'].max()], range_y=[df['y'].min(), df['y'].max()])

I set the min and max because eventually I will later move the origin to the median values of x and y.

Rangeslider code resets the x-axis, which is not the right direction. It also doesn't allow setting a start and end point*.*

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=True), type="date"))


fig.layout.sliders seems to be another option, but I haven't found an explanation that seems to lead in the right direction.

Thanks for any help.
